# Convert method pointer to integer, then call it

Tags: delphi

I'm wondering if this the following is possible or not, if yes, how? Code example please.

- How to store a **pointer to a method of a object** as an **integer value**?
- How to convert that integer value back to a 'method pointer' and **call it**?

What I want to do is store a 'method pointer' in the integer Tag value of a TComponent-derived object, and sometime later call the stored method. You can assume all met methods have the same definition.

Thanks!

Comment: method pointer wont fit into 32bit Tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do workaround, but it si not nice design...

```
var
  Method: ^TNotifyEvent;
begin
//Create New method 
  GetMem(Method, SizeOf(TNotifyEvent));
//Init target Tag
  Tag := Integer(Method);

//Store some method
  Method^ := Button1Click;

//call stored method
  Method := (Pointer(Tag));
  Method^(self);

//And don't forget to call in to object destructor...
  if Tag <> 0 then
    FreeMem(pointer(Tag));
```

Comment: thanks. Looks like your code is an example of Craig Peterson's description?

Comment: @Edwin, yep, that's what I would have posted if I'd had more time.

Comment: Thank you guys! It seems that maintaining a lot of such method pointers is a nightmare, looks like I should find an alternative approach... I got the idea anyway!

Comment: I don't know which answer to accept now, Craig's comes first, but GJ helped me to fully understand the approach with an example...

Answer (score 10):

No, it's not possible.  A method of object is equivalent to TMethod:

```
TMethod = record
  Code, Data: Pointer;
end;
```

The `Code` field is the address of the method, and the `Data` field is the hidden `Self` parameter that's passed into every object method.  The record is the same size as an Int64, so if you cast it as a plain Integer you'll lose half of it.

You could allocate a TMethod record on the heap using GetMem and then store the address of that in the Tag property, as long as you remembered to free it when you're done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I don't understand why Darian Miller's code worked...

Comment: It didn't.  The simple case posted didn't run into it, but there were fatal flaws that would have crashed a real program.