# How to store different method pointers in one container in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have the following method pointers

```
type
  TMethod1 = procedure(aValue: TType1) of object;
  TMethod2 = procedure(aValue: TType2) of object;
  .
  .
  TMethodN = procedure(aValue: TTypeN) of object;
```

I want to store them in one container.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488740/7579632), where a pointer to `TMethod1` is used to store one method and then call it. However, I would rather not use it for the following reasons:

- It allocates new block of memory and then later I should decide when to free it(never made it out of that area in one piece).
- It assumes all methods have the same definition, which is not my case.
- It is for one method. I have an array of them, and I do not see how I'm going to maintain such storage.

And there is an example in [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.MethodAddress) which uses a [`TMethod`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) approach, but in a different way where the second assumption above is no longer needed.  In the last step to call the method, I have to do an unsafe typecast, which again is something I would like to stay away from.

How do I accomplish this?

**Clarification** on how I'm going to use these methods:

I have a

```
procedure DoWork(aData: TType1; method: TMethod1);
begin
  store aData in a field;
  store method in my container; 
end;
```

Then later, process `aData` and call `method`.

Comment: What's the problem. Use `TList<TMethod>`. There are no issues with allocation. `TMethod` is a value type with automatic storage. That's the way if you have different types in the container. That is heterogeneous. If the types are the same, homogeneous, then use `TList<TMethod1>`. The former requires casting in order to call, the latter not.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How I call them again. and how to know which one of them I'm calling is the problem. What are you suggesting is in the documentation example.

Comment: It is not clear how do you intend to use such methods? There is not enough information provided to answer this question. Or should I say answer is simple use `TList<TMethod>`, however how can you use such stored methods depends on the context you didn't give.

Comment: Obviously you've got to keep track of the types

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I edited my question. I hope this fills the gap.

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense now. I thought I already understood.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why would you say so. the code is used in multi threading test and the time between storing the method and executing it is not instantaneous

Comment: That also makes no sense to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan which part does not make sense. I'm starting to losing you on this one.

Comment: The part where the time between storing and calling has an impact on the type has me lost.

Comment: @NasreddineAbdelillahGalfout If I understand you correctly you are trying to implement some structure to store necessary data for tasks that will be executed in the future. If you are then you might want to check OmniThreadLibrary how it is implementing its own tasks which follow such concept. Perhaps you don't know but Primož Gabrijelčič has made OmniThreadLibrary as an open source recently.

Comment: @SilverWarior I didn't know about that (OTL being open sourced). thank you for this. and yes that exactly what I was trying to do, but it proved to be harder than I thought.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry for that confusion. I meant that I need to make the call to the function in a later time. The TMethod did not provide a way other than typecasting. I didn't think of looking to this from the TTypes view (you mentioned this in previous comment). Remy has explained this in his answer. thank you for your efforts to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever you store in your container must be the same type.  You can use `TMethod` for that.  It is a special record type provided by the RTL to represents *any* `of object` method pointer.

The hard part is going to be calling the methods that are stored in your container.  You can't just call `TMethod` directly, you have to know the exact method type that it is pointing at, then type-cast it to that type.  For example:

```
var
  Field: TObject; // assuming TType... are class types
  Container: TList<TMethod>;

procedure DoWork<T>(aData: T; method: procedure(aValue: T) of object);
var
  M: TMethod;
begin
  M := TMethod(method);
  Field := aData;
  Container.Add(M); 
end;

procedure CallFieldMethod;
var
  M: TMethod;
begin
  M := Container[Index];
  if Field.ClassType = TType1 then
  begin
    TMethod1(M)(TType1(Field));
  end
  else if Field.ClassType = TType2 then
  begin
    TMethod2(M)(TType2(Field));
  end
  ...
end;

...

procedure TSomeClass.MethodForType1(aValue: TType1);
begin
  // use aValue as needed...
end;

DoWork<TType1>(Type1Obj, MethodForType1);

...

procedure TSomeClass.MethodForType2(aValue: TType2);
begin
  // use aValue as needed...
end;

DoWork<TType2>(Type2Obj, MethodForType2);

...
```

Another solution is to not rely on specific types at all, and just define 1 method type for the container.  Let the caller of `DoWork()` decide what to do:

```
type
  TMyMethod = procedure(aValue: Pointer) of object;

var
  Field: Pointer;
  Container: TList<TMyMethod>;

procedure DoWork(aData: Pointer; method: TMyMethod);
begin
  Field := aData;
  Container.Add(method); 
end;

procedure CallFieldMethod;
begin
  Container[Index](Field);
end;

...

procedure TSomeClass.MethodForType1(aValue: Pointer);
begin
  // use TType1(aValue) as needed...
end;

DoWork(Type1Obj, MethodForType1);

...

procedure TSomeClass.MethodForType2(aValue: Pointer);
begin
  // use TType2(aValue) as needed...
end;

DoWork(Type2Obj, MethodForType2);

...
```

Comment: The first sentence from the beginning, answered the question. I can not store them all unless I find a way to make them all of one form. and you answered that as well. thank you very much for you answer.